# Flutter BottomSheet At Top Of Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im Looking to integrate a sheet that drops down from the top of the screen, containing a set of buttons and textfields. However, i cant find any widget suitable for doing this. Is there a way to reposition bottomsheet to achieve this?

Comment: What you define as bottomsheet? Can you please attach example of what you are trying to achive.